# Get WebMatrix C# array of objects from json array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object, webmatrix

Given that the json file (json object) looks like this (an array of objects):

```
{
    "job": [
        {
            "title": "Mechanic",
            "department": "Central Repair Department",
            "summary": "Repair and perform preventative maintenance to vehicles and equipment.",
            "qualifications": "High school diploma or equivalent, valid Oklahoma driver's license, general knowledge of operating principals of gasoline and diesel engines, and experience with mechanical repair of vehicles. Basic knowledge of hydraulics and equipment is also desirable.",
            "incentive": "",
            "wage": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Police Patrol Officer",
            "department": "Police Department",
            "summary": "Repair and perform preventative maintenance to vehicles and equipment.",
            "qualifications": "High school diploma or equivalent, valid Oklahoma driver's license, general knowledge of operating principals of gasoline and diesel engines, and experience with mechanical repair of vehicles. Basic knowledge of hydraulics and equipment is also desirable.",
            "incentive": "",
            "wage": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get an array of objects, plotted with these values?

Please only answer if you are familiar with how to do this in WebMatrix's C# (This is different than regular C#, that is, there is no JsonReader method, no JObject method, nor other methods that other C# suggestions have indicated).  Although, I suppose it is '*possible*' that I could not have found the right using directive for some of these methods, but again the subtle differences in WebMatrix have left me with no way to find that information, if it is indeed there.

Also, I have no idea what LINQ is or how to employ it, nor do I care to, unless it is absolutely the best/easiest way.

Some non-static methods I have noticed in WebMatrix that have to do with json include 'DynamicJsonObject' and 'DynamicJsonArray', however, whether pathing to the file [using Server.MapPath or not] or just giving it the full json file stored as a single string variable, nothing I have tried to use with these methods has been successful.

Is there no easy way to simply create a C# array of objects from a json array of objects?

Thanks for any help! Please let me know if you require any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Json Helper](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/160/WebMatrix-Working-With-The-JSON-Helper) to decode the JSON to a dynamic object. Assuming that the JSON you posted above is in a file called JsonFile.txt, the following will do it:

```
@{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/JsonFile.txt"));
    var data = Json.Decode(json);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @foreach(var j in data.job){
            <h3>@j.title</h3>
            <div>@j.summary</div>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: AHH! I just knew it had to be more simple than I was making it. I was already working on trying to extract the data, one 'ReadLine' at a time (testing for stuff like .Contains("\"title: \"")) and then shoving each property into multiple <List>s. Thank God I don't have to go through with that sloppy of an approach. Google is insanely helpful in this line of work, but sometimes, I wonder why I can't find simple examples (like this) of what I am trying to find. Thanks so much! I will try this and be right back!

Comment: Of course, this works perfectly! Now I can work with this in the same way that I would if I were to use jQuery's $.getJSON (or $.ajax...), but I don't have to worry about that mess on the client-side! I am glad that my hang-up caused me to try Lists though, since if I want to declare an array-like object without setting a size, Lists seem the only way to go for C#.

Comment: I don't suppose this helper will work in reverse (it's okay if it doesn't I can rewrite the json file line for line if I have to...).

Comment: Yes - it works "in reverse". You use the `Encode` method to do that. Read the article I linked to.

Comment: Dangit! I missed another link. Why don't they fix the link color? Thanks again and sorry for the super dumb question. Saw the encode method, thanks to intellisense (did I spell that right?), but it was too late to delete the comment, I think.